# Substract value with previous value based on the condition in another column

Tags: .net, excel, vba, excel-formula

Need help in code for checking two conditions in column D values (fig1) of alternate rows, if conditions are true then subtract respective time values from the time column (column B).

Fig1
[image: Image showing Actual data in Indian language]

In English charecters
[image]

### It should check for all rows.

[image]

*respective time values

Comment: Your if formula is not valid: Try `=IF(AND(D2="A",D3="B"),B2-B3)`

Comment: Agree, and tried corrected formula which is not working, it is not showing subtracted value (B3 - B2).

Comment: that means your if condition is false. Which formula did you use? Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: (IF(AND(D2="ब", D3="ग"), (B3-B2), 0)) OR(if(AND(D2="ग", D3="ब"), (B3-B2), 0) )  - I have tried either condition in one cell

Comment: Formulas must start with a `=` please be much more specific! [Edit] your question instead of a comment so you can format it correctly. Is that one formula or 2? You will probably need more than one sentence to explain it properly.

Comment: =OR(IF(AND(D2="ब",D3="ग"),(B3-B2),0), IF(AND(D2="ग",D3="ब"),(B3-B2),0)) - Updaed.  It is showing result as "True"

Comment: Should be `=IF(OR(AND(D2="ब",D3="ग"),AND(D2="ग",D3="ब")),(B3-B2),0)`

Comment: Yes, it worked.  Thank @Pᴇʜ.  Can you let me know if it can be done in VBA script? If you know.

Comment: It can be done with VBA but since you can do it with a simple formula there is no need. Formulas are Excels strength so use them. Also this is no free coding service so you will need to write that code yourself. And if you get stuck or errors you can ask a question to it.

Comment: Since I have to create around 160 conditions for all the rows (60k), I am looking for some help in code.  I am not from coding background.  Anyways, thanks for the solutions, it helped for now. :)

Comment: We can only help if you start doing it on your own, post your code and ask a question to it. We cannot write the code for you.